# Error: executing module function 'setInfo'

Tags: ios, facebook, cordova

I have two problems: (IOS + XCode + PhoneGap)

1. After doing Hackbooks Facebook login I load an iframe which loads fine. When I click a like button from my app, it takes me to a Facebook login page. How come it does that when I'm already connected?
2. When the login page of Facebook comes up and I sign in, I get a blank page and I get a console error saying: "Error: executing module function 'setInfo' in module 'cordova/plugin/ios/device'. Have you included the iOS version of the cordova-1.9.0.js file?" I have the JS file in my WWW folder.

Can someone please give me a hand?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this:

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/guide_upgrading_ios_index.md.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about Facebook logging so I can't help much with Question 1, but for Question 2 it sounds like you are getting redirected after login to a page that does not include cordova-1.9.0.js.

Your index.html must be including the js file for you app to be doing anything, but apparently you are getting redirected back to a different page, so make sure that page also has a script tag for cordova-1.9.0.js.

Answer (score 0):

You need this:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.9.0.js">
    </script>
</head>
```